# Roles Dissapeared after package ran.

Tags: sql, ssas, roles

I have a reports package that runs once a quarter that reports software license data to the management staff of each department. I created roles in the Analysis Server in the Database Manager, limiting each manager to only see their departments data. When I ran the package this morning it wiped out all of the roles that had been created, thus not allowing anyone to see their report on the report server. Any idea what may cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little trial and error(s) I figured out this problem.

I was simply adding the roles on the Management Studio side and not to the solution itself.
Once I added the roles to the solution and processed it the roles stayed and were not wiped out like my previous attempts.